# Using base classes to add objects to a collection

Tags: c#

I have two custom objects, lets say `Cat` and `Dog`.  I want to create an `observable collection` that can hold either of these objects, as they are very similar. Can I use base classes to do this?

If so, would you mind providing a quick example.

And if I do use a base class, does that mean if I want to use common fields, I should put those into the base class?

EDIT: I'm hoping to then bind a WPF datagrid to the properties of these objects.  I don't know if it's possible to bind a datagrid in WPF to two different kind of objects...

Comment: upcast can be done easily and internally by the compiler(Cat->Animal).But downcast wud fail(Animal->Cat)

Comment: @Anirudha makes a good point and eludes to what I was trying to express.  It depends on the usage.  Maybe you don't care about Cat vs. Dog from the observable point.  It depends.

Comment: It is possible to bind the base class.  As wlabaj mentioned, if you need to downcast, it's a bit more costly.  Your other design option is to make the type of animal an enumeration of a single class.  You then bind the "Dog" and "Cat" from the Pet/Animal class.  It just depends on the need.  Does Dog/Cat need to do anything?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, in that case you can use a base class:

```
public class Pet
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public void Run() { }
}

public class Cat: Pet
{
    public string Meow()
    {
        return "Meow";
    }
}

public class Dog :Pet
{
    public string Bark()
    {
        return "Whow";
    }
}
```

Notice however, that when you place instances of both classes in one collection you can access **only** members of the **base** class.
So this code is valid:

```
var collection = new ObservableCollection<Pet> {new Cat(), new Dog()};

foreach (var pet in collection)
{
   pet.Run();
}
```

but you cannot use methods Meow() and Bark() unless you use explicit casting.

Be careful with moving too many members to the base class - in the example above Meow() doesn't make sense for the Dog and Bark() for the Cat. If you need to use some method specific to the derived class you could check the type with:

```
pet.GetType()
```

and then cast object to the derived type:

```
var cat = (Cat)pet;
cat.Meow();
```

Comment: Regarding your suggestion of using `pet.GetType()` to check for a derived class, I'd suggest using `is` to check instead (or `as` cast with null check) +1 for warning against moving too many members to the base class.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can use a base class say animal. And yes if they have common fields such as name, type, etc.. they can go in there.

```
class Animal {
    public String name;
}
```

Then just extend that. But you can also extend the functionality.

```
class Dog extends Animal {
    public void bark();
}
```

Now anything that asks for something of type Animal can receive Dog.

```
public void addToCollection(Animal animal)
addToCollection(new Dog());
```

This is actually the backbone for Java's Object.

Comment: He's using c#, but concept still applies :)

Comment: Been a while since I coded c# and it usually comes naturally when inside VS, but, isn't it Class Dog : Animal in C#?

Comment: your right (: == extends) lol. Stack needs code completion. ctrl + space

Comment: @FrankSposaro It'd be nice, but assuming the code completion is based off of VS, there is no completion for inheritance syntax anyway (short of type-completion once you start typing a specific type)

Answer (score 0):

Yes to the properties, that's sort of the point of base classes.  You express the commonality in the base and the specificity in the derived classes.  As for whether the base class is the best place for an observable collection, well, it depends.  You need to give some more insight into the need and the expected usage.  It's doable though.

Check out [ObservableCollection<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx) also.